# More efficient way of setting case-based variables in struct using enum

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, enums

I'm currently trying to rebuild one of my smaller, earlier projects that is a web browser. One feature that I'm trying to implement is pretty URLs and search terms. Meaning, after typing in a search query or a loadable URL into the TextField, instead of displaying the full URL, it makes it a readable (or *pretty*) search term/URL.

Right now, I have struct named `Live`, and it holds 3 variables: `searchTerm`, `prettyURL` and `fullURL`. When a user loads a search term, the TextField displays the `searchTerm`. When a user loads a URL, the TextField will display `prettyURL` until the user goes to enter a new address – in which case, the TextField will change to `fullURL` (similar to iOS Safari).

A very simple concept, but my end goal here is to have a function that sets the correlating type via an enum named `LiveType` in the most efficient way possible. Right now, I feel I have far too many lines of code for the function I desire.

I'm aiming for something like this: `Live.set(query, forType: .searchTerm)`. This is what I have right now:

**Live.swift**

```
struct Live {
    
    static var searchTerm = ""      // ie. "hello world"
    static var prettyURL = ""       // ie. "google.com"
    static var fullURL = ""         // ie. https://google.com/...
    
    // BAD FUNCTION: Doesn't make use of LiveType.setLive
    static func set(_ query: String, forType: LiveType) {
        switch forType {
        case .search: searchTerm = query
        case .pretty: prettyURL = query
        case .full: fullURL = query
        }
    }
    
}

enum LiveType {
    
    case search
    case pretty
    case full
    
    var setLive: String {
        switch self {
        case .search: return Live.searchTerm
        case .pretty: return Live.prettyURL
        case .full:   return Live.fullURL
        }
    }
    
}
```

Ideally, I would like something much more compact. Something like this:

```
static func set(_ query: String, forType: LiveType) {
    forType.setLive = query
}
```

However, I have not been able to get it working. Could anyone possibly shed some light? Also, if I'm making this much longer and more complex than it needs to be, I'm very open to alternative methods. Maybe I don't need an enum or a struct, great! I would love to learn what that may be for improving my programming style. This is purely a learning experience for me!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a function that recognizes user input? For example, if the user writes google.com does the prettyURL variable become equal to google.com?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. What does `setLive` function supposed to do (right now, it's a getter, so it doesn't set anything). What does `Live.set` supposed to do? Does is set the property based on the correct `LiveType` parameter? Why not just set the property directly? But mostly, it's unclear what you want to optimize for when you say "most efficient" - fewest lines of code? That's not always the best thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't need `struct Live` for storing the `query` `String` for `enum LiveType`. You can simply use [**associated values**](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) in `enum LiveType` instead, i.e.

```
enum LiveType {
    case search(String)
    case pretty(String)
    case full(String)
}
```

Now, you can create a LiveType instance like so,

```
let liveType = LiveType.search("hello world")
```